# How to label the number of points within a concave_hull avoiding duplicate counting

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

From a layer of points with the "CLASS" field reported with 3 different values, I apply the following expression to draw the concave polygon for each different value:

```
concave_hull(
            collect(
                $geometry,
                group_by:=overlay_nearest(@layer,"CLASS"))
                ,0.2)
```

Next, I use an expression to label the percentage of points within each concave hull polygon:

```
round(
with_variable(
    'num',
    concave_hull(
            collect(
                $geometry,
                group_by:=overlay_nearest(@layer,"CLASS"))
                ,0.2),
    aggregate(
        @layer,
        'count',
        1,
        within ($geometry, @num) or intersects ($geometry, @num)
    )
)

/ count('')  * 100.0,0) || ' %'
```

As can be seen, the total value is 103 % because it seems that there is a point that is count by duplicated in two different concave hull polygons:

[image]

How could I fix the label expression so that it takes this possibility and so that the percentage is balanced?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you create the polygons based on the `class` field. So why don't you use the same `class` field to calculate the percentage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you want to number the points per hull and the hull is based on the value in the `class` field, you can base your expression on this and don't have to complicate yourself with the hull's geometries:

`round (count (class,group_by:=class) / count (class) * 100, 0)`

[image]

---

By the way, better construct your hull with a simpler expression:

```
concave_hull(
    collect(
    $geometry,
    group_by:="class"),
    0.2
)
```